# Show login form before main form

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I'm having problems with the navigation between the forms. I have created an Android Firemonkey Mobile Application using Delphi XE5.

I currently have a Login Form and the Main Form, now I want advice on how to handle the Login Form to appear before the Main Form.

Comment: start your application with the main form hidden, in the formcreate event of your main form create your login form and show it modallly. Depending on the results of the login form, show your main form or terminate your application.

Comment: Each "form" is full screen on device, so I don't think you even need to hide the main form.

Comment: I have tried doing that and it did not work, is there any alternative?

Comment: Because whenever I create my Login form in the FormCreate of the Main Form...the Main form still appears first and when I create the Login form in the FormActivate event then thats when the Login form appears first but I cant settle for the FormActivate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Project Options, under forms, select the LogonForm to be auto-created, and move all other forms out of the list.

Now when you start your application, the Logon form will show as the first (and only) form.

Once logged on, you can create the other forms as needed.

Comment: You might also want to consider setting the Application.MainForm to be your Main form once you've logged in otherwise some processes will still be using the Logon form (the first form created using CreateForm() sets the MainForm) and could potentially appear behind the Main form because they are parented to the Logon form.